# Rails 4- My text_field value in my edit form is different than the actual value

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

This is for a todo app that I'm working on.  The create, update, and destroy actions have been ajaxified.  After a task has been created, you can set the date in the edit form.  The problem is when I create 2 tasks or more, and update them, all the values in the edit text fields get switched up.  Heres a screenshot [image]

My task partial:

```
<div class= 'task <%= task.priority %>' id='user_task_<%=task.id%>' >
  <span class='row row-fluid'>
    <span class='col-xs-9'>
      <% if task.due_date ==nil %>
        <h5 class='small'>Due Date</h5>
      <% else %>
        <%= datetime_format(task.due_date) %>
      <% end %>
    </span>

      <%=link_to(edit_task_path(task),remote:'true') do %> 
      <span class='col-xs-1.7'>
        <span id='edit_<%=task.id%>' class= 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
      </span>
      <% end %>
          <%=link_to task, method:'delete', remote:'true', data:{confirm:'Are you sure?'} do %> 
      <span class='col-xs-1.3'>
        <span id='edit_<%=task.id%>' class= 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
      </span>
      <% end %>

    </span>

       <br>
    <span class='row row-fluid'>

      <div class= 'tasks-description col-xs-12'>
        <%= task.description %>
        <span class= 'col-xs-12 edit_popover <%=task.priority %>' id= 'edit<%=task.id%>'>
          <%= render 'edit_form', task: task %> 
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

this is my edit form partial

```
   <%= form_for task, method:'put', remote:'true' do|f| %>   
  <div class='form-group'>
     <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: 'create a task', value: task.description%>   
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.text_field :due_date, id:"'due_date_'#{task.id}", class:'date', placeholder: 'due date' %>   </div>
   <hr>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= button_tag(type:'patch', class:"btn btn-default btn-xs edit-btn", id:'update-btn') do %>
      <span>Save and Close</span>   
  </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('.date').each(function(){
    $(this).pickadate();
  });
</script>
```

This is my update.js.erb:

```
$('#user_task_<%=@task.id%>').replaceWith("<%= j render 'tasks',task:@task %>")
```

When I inspect the element, the values are as it should be.  But clearly in the text field it's not.

UPDATE:  I think this is definitely a jquery issue.  When I remove remote:true from my form, the problem doesn't occur.  So how should I properly replace updated content with jquery?

Comment: What is your `Controller action` for `edit`?

Comment: My edit is `@task=Task.find(params[:id])` and my update is   `@task=Task.find(params[:id])` and `@task.update_attributes(task_params)`

Comment: Could you try changing your `form_for` call to: `form_for @task` instead of `task`? I've compared your code with mines and I'm not sure what's causing the problem. That's the only part that differs.

Comment: in my index I have `render @tasks`.  Thats why `task` works for my form.